# API запрос Axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Я написал вот такой API POST запрос на PHP и все прекрасно работает, но вопрос в том, что мне нужен этот запрос на Axios так как я к нему привяжу VueJS.

Помогите написать этот запрос на Axios.

```
$remote_url = 'https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/address';

        $data = array(
            'query' => 'Москва',
            'count' => 10
        ); 

        $authorization = "Authorization: Token *********";

        $ch = curl_init($remote_url);

        $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $authorization)); 

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $decode = json_decode($result);

        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let remote_url = 'https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/address';
let data = {
    'query' : 'Москва',
    'count' : 10
};
let token = 'твой_токен';
let config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token}
};
axios.post(remote_url, data, config).then(response => {
    // тут что-то связанное с ответом сервера
}).catch(error => {
    // тут обработка ошибки или вывод в консоль
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, НО... Самый большой вопрос был с авторизацией, проклятый header, подскажи пожалуйста, как быть с авторизацией? Куда вставлять?

Comment: @GermanMakarenko обновил ответ, добавил авторизацию

Comment: Даааа, это работает))) Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @GermanMakarenko ну ещё бы xDDD не за что :)